# "bundle format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable" error message results when trying to codesign app created using pyinstaller

Tags: python, macos, codesign

I have an app built using python and pyinstaller. The GUI is based upon tkinter.

When I attempt to sign it, I entered the following:

```
 codesign -s "Paul F (TeamID)" -v --deep --timestamp --entitlements 
 /Users/fishbacp/Desktop/entitlements.plist -o runtime 
 /Users/fishbacp/Desktop/dist/My_Application.app
```

The entitlements.plist. was included since it is apparently needed if binaries are built using pyinstaller. It's short and can be viewed at https://haim.dev/posts/2020-08-08-python-macos-app/

The error message I receive states

```
  bundle format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable
  In subcomponent:
  /Users/fishbacp/Desktop/dist/My_Application.app/
  Contents/MacOS/PyQt5/Qt/qml/QtQml/Models.2
```

I looked inside the Models.2 folder and see three items: libmodelsplugin.dylib, plugins.qmltypes, qmldir.

I'm not sure how to remedy this error. The only app I've signed and had notarized was extremely simple.

Answer (score 2):

The problem stems from the presence of the period in the name of Models.2 folder. A workaround, in the form of a script, is posted at https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Recipe-OSX-Code-Signing-Qt

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me. Of course after running the python script to fix the files, you simply run the `codesign` command again to sign the app and it should work.